# Saving AND using memchr's return value, in if? "if ( ptr = memchr(str1, '4', sizeof(str1)) )"?

Tags: c

Problem: if you do

```
if ( ptr = memchr( str1, '4', sizeof(str1) ) )
{
    // do stuff using ptr
}
```

then you'll enter and do "stuff" every time.
But if you just do

```
if ( memchr( str1, '4', sizeof(str1) ) )
{
    // would do stuff but don't have ptr!
}
```

then you'll enter but you won't have the pointer to where '4' is inside str1.
I need to evaluate and do stuff for several possibilities ie if '4', else if '7', else if '1', etc.

So what's the most efficient method to both evaluate if that character exists, and use the pointer returned if it does? Surely it's not

```
if ( memchr( str1, '4', sizeof(str1) ) )
{
    ptr = memchr( str1, '4', sizeof(str1) )
    // do stuff using ptr
}
```

Comment: No, your first statement is not true. If you do `if (ptr = memchr(...)) { }` you won't enter the if-block if the character is not located, since `memchr()` returns `NULL`, which in turns evaluates to false.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(str1)` will not do what you expect if `str1` is a pointer, rather than an array.

Comment: In the first option, it's not evaluating the NULL, it's evaluating the assignment of null to ptr, which would return true, just like if you wrote "if (ptr = 0)" or "if (ptr = 1)"-- the assignment completes successfully and returns 1.

Comment: @Rancur3p1c: Assignment returns the value of the expression assigned. That's why something like `a=b=c;` works. Did you actually try it? Are you confusing `=` with `==`?

Comment: @Rancur3p1c: No, you're wrong.  The assignment operator always returns the value being assigned (NULL in this case), not "1 if successful".  It's not a comparison operator -- the reason that chaining assignments like `a = b = c = 0` works at all is because it returns the value being assigned, and it binds from right to left.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know that it returns the value assigned. No, wasn't confusing with ==.

Comment: if someone wants to put that into an answer I can give credit where due...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operator returns the value being assigned, which (along with right associativity) is why `a=b=c;` works. So your first example will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

do the memchr and assign the return value then do the if.  like this:

```
ptr = memchr(str1, '4', sizeof(str1));
if (ptr)
{
  // do stuff using ptr;
}
```

Comment: Even though the OP's "problem" isn't a problem at all, I like this suggestion because it avoids the potential for confusing assignment with comparison.